# ASP.NET MVC 3 File Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, filesystems

I apologize for the vague title - I am new to ASP.NET MVC coming from PHP, and I have teamed up with a .NET developer that has a webforms background.

When working with MVC in PHP, all of my files are visible on the server - that is to say, I can go into any of my model, view and controller files and edit any of the code remotely without a problem.

In .NET MVC, I couldn't find the controller or model files, so I asked the developer how the webpage is being put together, and he told me about how .NET compiles code into .DLL files and that I am unable to access this. I wanted to view a controller to see how it was pulling together my views, but didn't even see a controller folder on the server.

To me, something about this doesn't sound right, but I am not sure because of my lack of experience in .NET. Can someone provide input as to if this is the typical .NET scenario, and if not, what is he doing wrong? Should I take this as a red flag? Keep in mind that .NET MVC is new to both of us.

Thanks!

Comment: Even if the application files are compiled into DLLs, he should have the source files. Ask him for the source files or access to the version control system if he uses one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code files because these code files was compiled into DLL files during Publish process. It's not strange - it's even better because of performance reasons. It's common scenario for all ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC applications.

You can deploy yor application via XCopy deployment (to have all .CS files etc.): simply copy all files to destination folder. Then your site will be compiled (into App_temp destination) by runtime on first run. Your .CS files will still be in place.

You can read more about Publishing procees here:

[Walkthrough: Publishing a Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Publishing Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)